# how to import .sql file in mysql database using talend ETL tool

Tags: mysql, talend

I want to import .sql file to mysql database using talend ETL tool and my machine is windows.

what i tried is used tSystem and write the command is

```
"cmd C:/xampp/mysql/bin>mysql -u root demo <C:/xampp/mysql/bin/localhost.sql"
```

when i run this i got this:

```
Starting job sqlfile at 10:51 04/09/2013.


[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3440
[statistics] connected
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\talend\TOS_DI-Win32-r104014-V5.3.1>
[statistics] disconnected
Job sqlfile ended at 10:51 04/09/2013. [exit code=0]
```

on console, i haven't got any error. but when i opened my demo database it doesn't contain anything.

please can any one tell where i am wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use tMysqlBulkExec to load your sql file ?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. This is a strange approach. You don't even need Talend to to that the way you're doing

Comment: @Julien Boulay how to use tMysqlBulkExec. i am new to talend.

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL commands in your ".sql" file do not change and you want a "one shot" interactive execution, you could use '**tMysqlRow**' and define :

- the 'connection parameters' to your database,
- the 'query' (using the SQL Builder to upload the content of your '.sql' file)
- ignore the 'schema' definition since the SQL commands will be consistent by themselves

The configuration of tMysqlRow is explained here :
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide53EN/tMysqlRow

You can read a usage scenario here (the component is a 'tDBSQLRow' but it also applies on 'tMysqlRow') :
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide53EN/tDBSQLRow

Answer (score 0):

If want to connect XAMPP Mysql to Talend then do following

in F:\xampp_new\mysql\bin\my.ini change as follows wait_timeout = number interactive_timeout = number connect_timeout = number bind-address=127.0.0.1 Then restart mysql in xampp

And select Mysql version 5 in DB Version 5

Cheer!!!